# Inline Fancybox 2 Not Working

Tags: php, jquery, html, fancybox

I've been trying to get links to inline content working in Fancybox 2, but have not been able to so. All that displays is:

> The requested content cannot be loaded. Please try again later.

How may I fix this? It even happens on Fancybox's own demo (go to http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/, and click "Inline" under "Various Types").

Comment: It works for me. I checked the demo -> Various Types -> Inline and it displayed some content.

Comment: I tried the demo and it works for me as well.

Comment: Have you tried it in another browser? There may be some strange setting causing it to not load in your current browser.

Comment: Thanks so much for replying! I figured-out that it was an incompatibility with a Safari Extension called NinjaKit.

Answer (score 0):

Found in some blog, something probably not documented (or not pretty well done), that adding a `class="fancybox.ajax"` to the link works, and it did for me.